# Does the graphics card amd radon rx 550 work with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, thinkpad

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Thinkpad E580.

The driver was not installed when i installed Ubuntu. So I downloaded amdgpu-pro from AMD. But it is still not working. I found out that the screen is currently powered by the intel chip.

And the Laptop is not certified by Ubuntu, and AMD says, the driver is currently only in beta. Is there a driver for this graphics card from any source other than AMD? Or should I just wait until I can get the driver from AMD?

Comment: All newer AMD GPUs shoud have "amdgpu" auto-loaded in Ubuntu. That driver comes with the linux kernel, so there is no need to install anything extra. If you want to use "amdgpu-pro", it is your choice. I don't know if you should wait or not.

Comment: Open the **Software & Updates** app in Ubuntu and go to the "Additional Drivers" tab. This is how you install proprietary drivers in Ubuntu. Downloading and installing from websites is not recommended.

Comment: @user68186 This is / was the AMD recommended way.

Comment: @RobAu The AMD recommended way is generic, and aim for all Linux distributions. The **Ubuntu recommended way** is for Ubuntu. The Ubuntu developers test their way to make sure that it works with Ubuntu.